# Which are the 2 interfaces which every class in Java implements by default

Tags: java

I was asked a question in one of the technical interviews. Which are the 2 interfaces which every class in Java implements by default. Looking for answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are no interfaces implemented by classes by default. There is only one class which is inherited by default is [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a trick Question.

Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone() to see that Object itself implements no interfaces.

Are you sure they didn't ask you to name two methods every class has?